# How are application updates delivered to the customer using code deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, deployment, aws-code-deploy

How could I deploy the code from my `S3` bucket to someone else's code deploy application?

For example, I push the code to my `S3` bucket using:

```
aws deploy push --application-name CodeDeployApplication --s3-location 
s3://cd-deploy-test-bucket/testdeploy.zip --source ./testdeploy
```

Now, I want my customer to deploy the application himself, once it has been pushed to my `S3` bucket? Is that even possible.

How are *updates/upgrades* delivered to the customer using code deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You just need to make sure the customer has the permissions to access your S3 bucket. You can add that by adding the customer account to the bucket permissions. Once that is done, you just need to provide the customer with the s3 link to the application in your bucket. Your customer can then create an application, deployment group with code deploy and specify the s3 revision to deploy.

For deployment updates, you can use code deploy triggers.